# RabbitMq и Masstransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Использую `Masstransit` для работы `RabbitMq`.

Ниже приведен код **Publisher:**

```
// Publisher
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x => {
            x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });
        });

        var busHandle = bus.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            bus.Publish(new Message() { Text = i.ToString() });
        }

        busHandle.Stop();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

и **Subsriber:**

```
// Subsriber
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {
            var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });

            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestSubscriber", e =>
              e.Handler<Message>(a => 
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(a.Message.Text);
                  return Task.FromResult(0);
              }));
        });

        var busHandle = bus.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
        busHandle.Stop();
```

Если заглянуть в метрику `RabbitMq`, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно заметить, что кол-во сообщений, которые публикуются (`Publisher`) составляет в среднем `7406` в сообщений/секунду. А сообщений, которые доставляются (`Subsriber`) - `2531` сообщений/секунду. Получается что издатель (`Publisher`) публикует сообщения практически в **3** раза быстрее, чем их получает подписчик (`Subsriber`). Такое поведение является нормальным и можно ли как-то ускорить процесс получения сообщений подписчиком (`Subsriber`)?